# R While Loop using a self-made function doesn't work as need

Tags: r, dataframe, function

I'm new to R programming (used in my study) and currently learning it through datacamp with RStudio. I have an assignment for learning R as below:

I have a matrix called `census` like this:

```
             Area Inhabit   XCOORD   YCOORD s_tot_family rev_avg
11001A00- 52.6211    2104 151.3999 202.4849          931   28356
11001A01- 66.4397    2731 151.1110 203.2089         1094   35508
11001A020 27.7954     845 150.4315 203.3277          327   41776
11001A030 42.7325     463 150.9282 203.8764          180   29008
11001A042 25.3009     422 151.6225 203.5632          152   54203
11001A052 33.3881    2451 151.0243 202.2535          948   31931
```

Rowname is the name of area_block, with each having a (X, Y) coordinate, number of inhabitants inside the area, average family income, and number of family.

The assignment is to write a function, for a random store with a coordinate `str_coord <- c(c,d)` and radius == b (default =5), print out a list containing: a matrix of blocks in the store's radius, the total number of inhabitants in the store radius, and weight average family income of families in the store radius.

This is my function:

```
trading_area <- function(census,b=5,c,d){
  str_coord <- c(c,d)
  distances <- c(sqrt((str_coord[1]-census[,3])^2+(str_coord[2]-census[,4])^2))
  selected_block <- subset(census, distances <=b)
  total_inhabit <- sum(selected_block[,2])
  mean_inc <- weighted.mean(selected_block[,6],selected_block[,5])
  target <- list(selected_block,mean_inc,total_inhabit)
  names(target) <- c("selected_block","mean_inc","total_inhabit")
  return(target)
    }
```

This function run okay with every c,d I put in, same result as If I calculate it manually, use no function.

Then, for next question: Now write code that allows you to do the following: starting in point c(89, 155), move east in steps of 2 kilometers till you find a trade area with a radius of 5 km that has at least 8,000 inhabitants and an average annual family income of at least €23,000, or till the X coordinate becomes greater than 230 (otherwise you may leave the territory of Belgium). In the course of this search process, save all considered store locations in a (gradually growing) matrix with the XY coordinates on the rows (thus, a matrix with two columns); similarly, save the number of inhabitants and average income for each considered store location also in a growing matrix with two columns.

I wrote a code as below with while loop, and print out change of X,Y coordinate and number of inhabitants and average income for each considered store location as matrices. X,Y coordinate changed with each 2km steps, but number of inhabitants and average income didn't change:

```
#1d
considered_xy <- matrix(str_coord,nrow = 2,byrow = TRUE,
                        dimnames = list(c("X.COORD","Y.COORD"),
                                        c("V1")))
inhainco <- matrix(c(total_inhabit,mean_inc),ncol = 2,byrow = FALSE,
                   dimnames = list(c("X1"),c("total_inhabit","mean_inc")))

while (str_coord[1]<229) {
  str_coord[1] <- str_coord[1]+2
  trading_area(census,5,str_coord[1],155)
  considered_xy <- cbind(considered_xy,c(str_coord[1],155))
  inhainco <- rbind(inhainco,c(target$total_inhabit,target$mean_inc))
  print(target)
}
```

The code just not worked  for each steps of X, no changes in total inhabitant or average income

Comment: hi there! welcome to stackoverflow! one tip - using `c` as a variable name is frowned upon generally, because it's already the name of the function c(), and it gets confusing - could lead to errors

Comment: have you tried `debug()`-ing the code already? If you're learning how to code/use R, it's usually where I start with these sorts of problems, and where I would go to with your example. Put all of the code inside a function `example_function`, make sure the function is created, then run `debug(example_function)`, then run the function. Step through the code to see where things break down

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion about C as the variable name, good advice. I have tried the debug function but it doesn't show any value information, function still run smoothly